# Windows filename gets mangled 

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.7

I am trying to open an image using open method of Image of PIL, but am getting the following error.

I have stored my image at `C:\a.jpg`.

```
>>> h1 = Image.open("C:\a.jpg").histogram()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    h1 = Image.open("C:\a.jpg").histogram()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\x07.jpg'
```

Comment: yes, it is an escaping problem as the answers note, but the information was there for you to see; you didn't ask for a file `C:\x07.jpg` but that's what the message said it tried to open. Why? Because `'\a'` is an escape for ASCII BEL (0x07) just like `'\n'` is an ASCII LF (0x0a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try escaping the back slashes...

```
>>> h1 = Image.open("C:\\a.jpg").histogram()
```

Answer (score 7):

You are having problem of escape character, using the method of @NelleshSharma or

```
Image.open(r'c:\a.jpg').histogram();
```